# Array stops working when i update the value of a key to 0

Tags: php, ajax

i have a code where sales are made on a sales modal(on an invoice page) with database entry.When a product for sale is selected, the pieces available for that product is entered into another input and on submission, the product id and pieces sold of the product is added to a session array.The purpose of this is because when sales are made it's added to a sales table on the invoice page, just in case the user decides to add too or subtract from the number of pieces of a particular product already on the sales table,let the sales modal (pieces available)input be up to date on the values to display instead of getting it from the database again.

here is a sample of the code i use in making a sales db entry and setting session array values:

```
    $productPieces = get_productPiecesForSale();//fetches product pieces from db
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];//product id
    $pieces = $_POST['pieces_sold'];// pieces sold
    $invoice_id = $_SESSION['invoice_id'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM sales WHERE product_id = '$id' AND invoice_id = '$invoice_id' LIMIT 1";// check if product is in the sales table already
    $sales_set = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    $sales = mysqli_fetch_array($sales_set);

    if(isset($sales['sales_key'])){

    $pieces_update = $pieces + $sales['pieces']; // adds db pieces to pieces sold

    if($pieces_update > $productPieces){

    if(in_array($product_id, $_SESSION['pieces_available'])){
    $key = array_search($product_id , $_SESSION['pieces_available']);
    $_SESSION['pieces_available'][$key+1] = '0';
    }  

//so that pieces can't be sold above what is available
    $query = "UPDATE sales SET pieces = '{$productPieces}'  WHERE product_id = '{$product_id }' LIMIT 1";
    $sales_set = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    }else{

    if(in_array($product_id , $_SESSION['pieces_available'])){
    $key = array_search($product_id , $_SESSION['pieces_available']);
    $_SESSION['pieces_available'][$key+1] = $productPieces - $pieces_update;
    }

    $query = "UPDATE sales SET pieces = '{$pieces_update}'' WHERE  product_id = '{$product_id }' LIMIT 1";
    $sales_set = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    }//if($pieces_update > $productPieces){

    }else{

    $_SESSION['pieces_available'][] = $_POST['product_id'];
    $_SESSION['pieces_available'][] = $_POST['pieces_remaining'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO sales() VALUE()";
    $sales_set = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
    }
```

and here's the php code for my ajax i use to populate my sales form input

```
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
     $p = $_GET['p'];

     if(isset($_SESSION['pieces_available'])){//$_SESSION['pieces_available'] is set

       if(in_array($p, $_SESSION['pieces_available']) !== false){//product_id is in array
         $key = array_search($p, $_SESSION['pieces_available']);
         $pieces = $_SESSION['pieces_available'][$key+1];
         echo $pieces;
       }else{//product_id is not in array
    $query = "SELECT pieces FROM products WHERE product_id = '{$p}' LIMIT 1";
    $result_set = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
    echo $result['pieces'];
       }  

     }else{//$_SESSION['pieces_available'] isn't set
    $query = "SELECT pieces FROM products WHERE product_id = '{$p}' LIMIT 1";
    $result_set = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set);
    echo $result['pieces'];
     }

    }
```

Everything works how i want it to work, until i update the pieces of a product already existing on the sale table that the  pieces remaining now becomes 0, then my sales form stops displaying the pieces available for a selected product. If the pieces remaining becomes any other number this doesn't happen.

well just in case let me add my ajax and html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function loadDoc2(str){
     if (str == "") { 
        document.getElementById("pieces_available").value = "";
        return;
    } else {
         //Check for browsers
         if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
             xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         }else{
             xhttp =  new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         //ajax onready
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("pieces_available").value = xhttp.responseText;
             }
         };
         xhttp.open("POST","url?p="+str,true);
         xhttp.send();
 }
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id='product_id' onchange='loadDoc2(this.value)'>
<option value=''>Choose products</option>
</select>
<input type='number' id='pieces_avaible' readonly/>
<input type='number' id='pieces' placeholder='enter pieces for sale'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Sales table screen shots: [saleTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlnAq.jpg)
Sales modal screen shots: [sale Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIKEb.jpg)

Comment: Can you add a couple of screenshots (working/not working) to help visualizing the code? Or if it's possible a link to the live site with step by step instructions on how to produce the error

Comment: i have added the screen shots of my sale modal and sales table below